# Letters into split array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have a bunch of letters on each line which is being outputted by the var `current`. I want to split them into an array and my desired output is shown below my code.

`current` prints out:

```
I
T
and so on...
each letter on a new line.
```

JS:

```
function check(event) {
    var current = event.target.innerText;
    var letters = current.split();
    for (i=0; i<letters.length; i++) {
        letters[i] = letters[i].replace(/\s/g,"").split("");
        console.log(letters);
    }
}

current output = [ [ 'I', 'T', 'U', 'M', 'A', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'D', 'I', 'U', 'T', 'E', 'L', 'N' ] ]
desired output = [ 'I', 'T', 'U', 'I', 'M', 'A', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'D', 'U', 'T', 'E', 'L', 'N' ]
```

My problem is that I have two square brackets on my current output. I just want one, as shown in the desired output.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is that I have two square brackets on my current output... I just want one as shown in the desired output @zerkms. Please let me know which part of the question you don't understand

Comment: So why do you have nested arrays there at first place? " which part of the question" -- the whole question is extra vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to flatten your array afterwards:

```
var flattened = [];
flattened = flattened.concat.apply(flattened, letters);
```

After that the `flattened` array will be a one-level flat array with all the letters.

From the other hand your `var letters = current.split();` operation makes no sense, so you should have done

```
var letters = current.replace(/\s/g,"").split("");
```

instead and it would just work (without any `for` loops at all).

Credits:

- [Merge/flatten an Array of Arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/251311)

Comment: You are the best! Both work like a charm! Second one is more efficient for my needs. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can call `current_output[0]` to give your `desired_output`:

```js
current_output = [[ 'I', 'T', 'U', 'M', 'A', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'D', 'I', 'U', 'T', 'E', 'L', 'N' ]];
desired_output = current_output[0]; //[ 'I', 'T', 'U', 'M', 'A', 'R', 'B', 'R', 'D', 'I', 'U', 'T', 'E', 'L', 'N' ] 
document.write(desired_output)
```

Comment: Thats a way to work around it... any way to get the desired result without doing this? I understand I have two `split()` which is causing this issues... if I remove the `var letters = current.split();` line... I get each letter on a different line